What species of bird is this?
We found this fledgling (location: Stellenbosch, Western Cape, South Africa) under a tree next to the road (the tree's branches are high up, so we could not put it back into the tree). We are trying to find out what species it is, what to feed it and how often it should be fed.
It seems quite healthy as it is chirping and flying around in the house.
Little bird found:

Welcome Amanda. I'm no expert so this is not an answer, just a suggestion in a comment, but it seems to resemble the red-billed buffalo weaver, a juvenile. If you scroll down the page on this bird ID site, you'll see the youngster that resembles your new companion. +Wikipedia article. Hopefully someone will come along who can give you something more definitive. It's thought inadvisable to offer dairy products as birds on the whole are not adapted to it, but insects/seeds should work. Mash first

This is an immature Cape Canary. It is really difficult to find reliable evidence of the fact, so a good answer will be hard to put together. Try googling "Cape Canary chick identification"
